# Prediction result is never less than 0.5 in Weka random forest classifier

Tags: java, weka, random-forest

I have a problem about the result of random forest classifier in Weka software.

After training when I apply my dataset as test set, the result of classifier (prediction part) is never less than 0.5! Thus I could not calculate the correct value for AUC in ROC curve.

Is it possible to calculate AUC by using prediction result in random forest classifier?